# рекурсивный поиск и создание нового массива

Tags: php

```
  <?php
    $arr = Array(
        254362 => Array(
            254370,
            254363
        ),
        254363 => Array(
            254369
        ),
        254357 => Array(
            254362,
            254359
        ),
        254359 => Array(
            254360
        ),
        Array(
            254357
        )
    );
```

Есть массив, нужно обойти рекурсивно и создать новый, например при выборе ключа 254362, получаем значения 254370, 254363 ищем полученные значения, как ключи вновь и т.д.
Новый массив должен иметь структуру, как в примере, но без незатронутых ключей при поиске.

В настоящий момент есть код:

```
    var_dump(get_childs($child_array, $id));

function get_childs($array, $id) {
    foreach ($array[$id] as $value) {
        $childs[$id] = $array[$id];
        get_childs($array, $value);
    }
    return $childs;
}
```

При его исполнении возникает ошибка `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: А вы уже пробовали что-то сделать, что не получается?

Comment: mnv, попробовал создать функцию, в ней foreach с последующим вызовом этой функции, но страница не прогружается...

Comment: Тогда предлагаю опубликовать код и сообщение об ошибке. И, кстати, почему речь о рекурсии, если структура исходного массива не рекурсивная, по крайней мере в примере?

Comment: `get_childs($child_array, $start_id);

function get_childs(&$array, $id) {
    foreach ($array[$id] as $key => &$value) {
   $childs[] = $array[$key];
            get_childs($array, $key);
    }
 return $childs;
}` ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Похоже, что бесконечная рекурсия. Попробуйте добавить условие выхода из рекурсии. Например, сейчас результат `get_childs()` никак не обрабатывается. А в вашем случае надо бы его мержить с имеющимся списком и не нырять дальше, если в нем уже есть элемент с переданным `$id` (обработанный)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша процедура может зацикливаться на данных в которых 2 id будут указывать друг на друга. В вашем примере таких не видно, но надо учитывать, что в вашем массиве присутствует элемент, отсутствие номера у которого может вводить в заблуждение:

```
    254363 => Array( 254369 ),
    ...
    254359 => Array( 254360 ),
    Array( 254357 ) <-- Вы думаете это 0й элемент ?
                        НЕТ - это следующий по номеру, за максимальным в вашем массиве
                        Т.е. 254364
```

А процедура с защитой от циклов и исключением других ошибок, типа отсутствующих элементов массива и не объявленной переменной `childs` должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php
 $arr = Array(
        254362 => Array( 254370,  254363 ), 254363 => Array( 254369  ),
        254357 => Array( 254362, 254359 ), 254359 => Array( 254360 ),
        254369 => Array( 253000 ), Array( 254357 )
    );

var_dump(get_childs($arr, 254362));

function get_childs(&$array, $id) {
   static $childs=[];
   static $allkey=[];
   if(!array_key_exists($id,$array)) return false;
   foreach ($array[$id] as $value) {
        $childs[$id] = $array[$id];
        if(!in_array($value,$allkey)) {
           $allkey[]=$value;
           get_childs($array, $value);
        }
    }
  return $childs;
}
?>
```